# How can I use a Java Optional object in Scala?

Tags: java, scala

I have to use a Java function in Scala, which takes arguments of type `Optional<Type>`, and the object I have to pass to it also comes from a Java library but is simply of type `Type`. How can I use that in Scala?

Is it OK, If I typecast it like this. Note that here `javaObj` comes from a Java library and is of type `Type`. But `someFunctionDefinedInAJavaLibrary` function here expects an argument of type `Optional<Type>`.

```
import java.util.Optional
....
// javaObj here is of type Type and comes from a Java library
val scalaObj: Optional[Type] = javaObj.asInstanceOf[Optional[Type]]
// someFunctionDefinedInAJavaLibrary's argument is of type Optional<Type>
val r = someFunctionDefinedInAJavaLibrary(scalaObj)
```

Comment: The easiest way would be to use [**scala-java8-compat**](https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat#converters-between-scalaoption-and-javautil-classes-optional-optionaldouble-optionalint-and-optionallong)

Comment: [scala-java8-compat](https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat) Ahhh, too late...

Comment: What is the question here? does Optional creation fail? can you not import it? Are you looking for an automatic conversion? Did you try to use it and get some exception? As it stands, it is unclear what you are actually asking for here.

Comment: What is `javaObj`? Why you want to typecast it to anything? What does it have to do with scala-java interop?

Comment: If it's of type `Optional[Type]`, then why are you trying to typecast it as `Optional[Type]`? With every edit it becomes less and less clear what you're asking. You are aware of the fact that you can use all Java objects in Scala code without any typecasts?

Comment: If javaObj is already a java Optional, then why do you need to typecast it before sending it to a java function? It is already the proper type. Give us some actual code from a failing use case, so that we can understand what you are actually trying to accomplish

Comment: Because If I don't do it, Scala compiler gives an error.

Comment: Then post that error, and the code that causes that error, so that we can see the actual problem.

Comment: Always include the error message you are getting in the question.

Comment: Well, then please provide a [mcve] with an actual error, not just bunch of comments about what you *think might cause* the error.

Comment: javaObj is of type Type, not Optional<Type>, but the function expects Optional<Type>

Comment: Here you claim that `javaObj` is of type `Type`, in the code your `asInstanceOf` claims that it is of type `Optional[Type]`. Both statements can't be true at the same time. If it blows up, then probably `javaObj` is indeed not an `Optional[Type]`.

Comment: If javaObj is supposed to be of type `Type` then post code where it actually is of that type, with a sample object which is created in the posted code, so that it's type is immediately obvious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be literally 1:1 the same expression as in Java:

```
someFunctionDefinedInAJavaLibrary(Optional.of(javaObj))
```

Just forget that `asInstanceOf` or `scala.Option` exist when invoking functions from your Java-API.

---

If you ever have to actually translate between Java's `Optional` and Scala's `Option`, you can use [scala-java8-compat](https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat) ([maven central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-java8-compat)), but it's not necessary in this particular case, because there are no `Option`s anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

`Some("abc").asInstanceOf[Optional[String]]` won't work because a Scala `Option` and a Java `Optional` are unrelated types.

You could include [a Java8-compatibility library](https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat#converters-between-scalaoption-and-javautil-classes-optional-optionaldouble-optionalint-and-optionallong) to convert between the types (just like the one for compatibility with Java collections that you may be familiar with), or just do it manually.

```
 def toJavaOptional[A](maybeA: Option[A]): Optional[A] = 
    maybeA.fold(Optional.empty)(a => Optional.of(a))

 def toScalaOption[A](maybeA: Optional[A]): Option[A] =
    if (maybeA.isEmpty) None else Some(maybeA.get)
```

---

> javaObj is of type `Type`, not `Optional<Type>`, but the function expects `Optional<Type>`

Then do the same thing you would in Java (which does not automatically "box" a `Type` into `Optional<Type>` either):

```
callJavaFunction(Optional.of(a))
```

You can use all Java API methods in Scala directly, including `Optional.of`.

Comment: It's still not obvious to me what Scala's `Option` has to do with the question in the first place. It seems just like a failure to get some types right while using a pure-java library from Scala.